# Openstack train aio installation issues

Tags: ansible, rabbitmq, openstack, yum

**The following command failed :**

```
 openstack-ansible setup-infrastructure.yml
```

**Result:**

```
 No package matching 'erlang-22.1.3-1.el7.x86_64' found available
```

(10 out of 10 Fails)

**Detail log:**

TASK [rabbitmq_server : Register a fact for the installed RabbitMQ version] ****
　skipping: [aio1_rabbit_mq_container-7aeeaf7f] => (item={'skipped': True, 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional result was False'})
　ok: [aio1_rabbit_mq_container-7aeeaf7f] => (item={'stderr_lines': [], u'changed': True, u'end': u'2021-03-12 07:50:27.659404', u'stdout': u'', u'cmd':
　u'rpm -qa | grep rabbitmq-server', u'failed': False, u'delta': u'0:00:00.259248', u'stderr': u'', u'rc': 1, u'msg': u'non-zero return code', 'stdout_li
　nes': [], 'failed_when_result': False, u'start': u'2021-03-12 07:50:27.400156'})
　TASK [rabbitmq_server : Compare installed version of RabbitMQ with new version variable] ***
　TASK [rabbitmq_server : include_tasks] *****************************************
　TASK [rabbitmq_server : include_tasks] *****************************************
　included: /etc/ansible/roles/rabbitmq_server/tasks/install_yum.yml for aio1_rabbit_mq_container-7aeeaf7f
　TASK [rabbitmq_server : Fail if installation method is not 'external_repo'] ****
　TASK [rabbitmq_server : Configure repositories] ********************************
　ok: [aio1_rabbit_mq_container-7aeeaf7f] => (item={u'description': u'RabbitMQ Erlang Packages from Bintray', u'name': u'rabbitmq_els-erlang', u'baseurl'
　: u'https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/erlang/el/7/$basearch', u'filename': u'els-erlang'})
　ok: [aio1_rabbit_mq_container-7aeeaf7f] => (item={u'description': u'RabbitMQ Server Rolling Repository', u'name': u'rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server', u'baseur
　l': u'https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/el/7/$basearch', u'filename': u'RabbitMQ'})
　TASK [rabbitmq_server : Install RabbitMQ packages] *****************************
　fatal: [aio1_rabbit_mq_container-7aeeaf7f]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'erlang-22.1.3-1.el7.x86_64' found available, ins
　talled or updated", "rc": 126, "results": ["No package matching 'erlang-22.1.3-1.el7.x86_64' found available, installed or updated"]}
　PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
　aio1 : ok=31 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=19 rescued=0 ignored=0
　aio1_galera_container-dc6e643a : ok=49 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=6 rescued=0 ignored=0
　aio1_memcached_container-2568ac10 : ok=14 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=4 rescued=0 ignored=0
　aio1_rabbit_mq_container-7aeeaf7f : ok=16 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=1 skipped=6 rescued=0 ignored=0
　aio1_repo_container-c0773ddc : ok=26 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=7 rescued=0 ignored=0
　aio1_utility_container-e84bda78 : ok=44 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=16 rescued=0 ignored=0
　EXIT NOTICE [Playbook execution failure] **************************************
　===============================================================================
　+ grep -q 'Playbook execution success' setup-infrastructure.out
　+ echo 'Failed to run the ansible playbook setup-infrastructure.yml'
　Failed to run the ansible playbook setup-infrastructure.yml
　+ sleep 1m
　+ (( c++ ))
　+ (( c<=4 ))
　+ return 1

Comment: Hi. This is not a programming question. It is therefore [off-topic](/help/on-topic) on SO. You might want to try https://superuser.com

Comment: Did your search results not include [this relevant issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/70081)? When you move your question to SuperUser.com please include the version of ansible you are using, as it matters. Reading the [how to ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) will go a long way toward improving your experience in the Stack Exchange network. Good luck